How to Set return of perl function in request header using nginx
Could anyone help me with nginx with a perl module?
I have already managed to create a function in Perl using the ubi8/nginx-124 image but I am not able to set the result of the function in the header.
0
Having this in nginx configuration file:
http {
   perl_modules /opt/app-root/etc/nginx/nginx-perl/;
   perl_require module1.pm;
   perl_set $test module1::handler; #it is not calling the function here, it is only called in the location block
}
location = /perl {
    perl module1::handler; #I've already tried with and without this line
    add_header X-My-Header $test; #I tried adding the header this way and from within the code with $r.But both without success
}

and this perl file:
package module1;;

use nginx;
sub handler {
    my $r = shift;
    my $foo = 'foo';

    $r->send_http_header("text/html");
    $r->header_out("WWW-Authenticate" => $foo);

    $r->print("<h3>SUCCESS:</h3>");
    return $foo;
}
1;


Have you looked at existing modules code? For instance: https://gist.github.com/kwmiebach/2f03baaae7e4f86f9573f1f30818d36f

Sorry, but what you sent me has nothing to do with what I need. The only thing that could be what I need would be the use of $r->header_out("X-Custom-Header", "CUSTOM_VALUE");, but as I mentioned, that's precisely what isn't working."

This is the correct way:
package module1;

use lib '/opt/app-root/etc/nginx/nginx-perl/';

use strict;
use nginx;

sub handler {
   my $r = shift;
   $r->header_out("X-Custom-Header", "CUSTOM_VALUE"); #This line has to be placed before of send_http_header
   $r->send_http_header("text/html");
   $r->print("Hello, world!");
   return OK;
}

1;
And the configuration file must to be:
http {
  perl_modules /opt/app-root/etc/nginx/nginx-perl/;
  perl_require module1.pm;
}
location = /perl {
  perl module1::handler;
}

Another way could be:
http {
  perl_modules /opt/app-root/etc/nginx/nginx-perl/;
  perl_require module1.pm;
  perl_set $foo module1::handler;
}
location = /perl {
  proxy_pass http://aplha.beta.com;
  proxy_set_header  "X-Custom-Header" $foo;
}

sub handler {
   return 'CUSTOM_VALUE';
}

